# Set non text content to DOM Element in Android

Tags: android, string, dom, document

**I read a html template from assets and want to add html into a certain div.**

I parse the template into a org.w3c.dom.Document and get the div as an org.w3c.dom.Element like this:

```
Element wrapper = doc.getElementById("wrapper");
```

I tryed adding my html text like this:

```
wrapper.setTextContent(article.getHtmlString());
```

Unfortunally all "<>" are beeing converted and look like this afterwards:

```
&lt;
```

I would appreciate a way of appending my html string in a fashion that doesnt break the tag's.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to regular expressions and using Strings replace method to fill in my html content after turning the document to String.

```
docHtmlString.replace("<div id='wrapper'>, "<div id='wrapper'>" + article.getHtmlString());
```

Not a real solution actually using dom but a working alternative when trying to add some html string content.